# Where is the constructor for InetAddress Class?

Tags: java

I know how to make an instance for the subjected class with it's static method , but there is something I can't understand, who the "The constructor InetAddress() is not visible" !!

it's a regular class not abstract and not final , and I have searched the whole class looking for a private constructor and i came back empty handed ..

I know there is an explanation for that and I need to know what is it please ??

Update : It's not duplicated question and it has nothing do do with the InetAddress class .. I am asking about something fundamental in JAVA ...

Regards

Comment: "I have searched the whole class looking for a private constructor and i came back empty handed" What do you mean? Are you saying you looked at the javadocs or at the actual source code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the actual source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for `InetAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html), I don't see any public constructors. Instead, I see several static factory methods. You should use one of these.

Comment: I know that .. as far as I know .. Java provide it's own contractor if the class doesn't declare one ?? so my question is how my IDE know that there is no Public contractor... please read my question again .

Comment: @user2764147 Because `InetAddress` **does** declare a constructor. Since the Javadocs show that the constructor is not `public` nor `protected`, we can safely assume that it is `private` and therefore not directly accessible. Note that private members are not listed in the standard javadocs.

Comment: there is not private constructor .. I have checked the same class in eclipse .. and there is not

Comment: My bad. [The constructor is package-private](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/net/InetAddress.java#InetAddress.%3Cinit%3E%28%29). This amounts to the same thing: you cannot create `InetAddress` objects directly.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with package-private (or default) access. Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: Thanks A lot friend .. you remind me of that .. I have read about that long time ago .. The question has been answered ... Thanks A million :)